# Windows 10: Out of Box (Default) Volume Level

Tags: windows-10, audio, sound-card

Really simple question but unable to find anything official, so here goes:

When installing Windows 10 what is the default volume of any given device output?

*e.g: Answers should be within range from 1 to 100*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

67, which is around ⅔ of the full volume. Below is a screenshot of a freshly installed Windows 10 (Enterprise LTSB). Logically you should find the same results in all other versions of Windows 10, e.g Pro, Home, Enterprise and Education editions.

[image: Volume at 67 in Windows 10]

Comment: Do you have any official record or reference ( that you can provide here ) or any calculations for the number you proposed ?

Comment: No, I do a lot of Windows installation for my friends and families. I've noticed the volume level and took a mental note. It helped that it's a rounded off 2/3. For affirmation I reckon [this is a user who just reporting the default volume](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/why-is-the-volume-set-to-67/78818815-e037-4ef3-8e71-85418ba44541) on the Windows forum.

Comment: @BorhnN hope you don't mind I added a screenshot and added some text, you were right, 67 seems the default. Thanks.